# Comparing char arrays to check if input is same

Tags: c, arrays

If I have 2 arrays, one which is in the code already, and another which is entered by the user, how do I check if the one entered by the user is found inside the other predefined array?

```
char array1[] = {abcdefghijklmn};
char array2[3];

printf("enter 3 letters: ");

for (int i = 0; a < 3; i++) {
scanf(" %c"; &array2[i]);
}

for (int a = 0; i < 14; a++) {
   for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
   if (array1 [a] == array2 [b])
      printf("located at %d ", array1[a]);
   }
}
```

I think my for statement only compares each element but not the whole word if a user types abc, how do I fix this in my for loop/ if statements?

Comment: `char *found = strstr(array1, array2);` if you terminate your string.

Comment: `if (array1 [a] = array2 [a])` <--- Watch out, you are using `=` when you should be using `==`. Also, you are not using `b` inside the `for` body

Comment: @Jbox please don't correct faults in the question in reponse to comments. It makes the topic hard to follow.

Comment: @Jbox `char array1[] = {abcdefghijklmn};` does not even compile. Why not post your proper code in the first place. "Oh... I have posted *something like my code*, please correct my typos."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for (int b = 0; b < 14; b++) 
{
     i=0;
     while(array2 [i] == array1 [b] && b<14 && i<4)
     {
          ++i;
          ++b;
     }
     if(i==3)
     {
         printf("\nlocated at %d ",b-3);
         break;//for single occurence
     }
}
```

**EDIT**: For calculating multiple occurences of a word just remove the `break` statement inside if condition.

Comment: what does i ==4 supposed to do?

Comment: check the edit its `i==3` which is the size of char array entered by user....If the consecutive chars of array2 are equal to that of array1 ,**word** is present in the array..

Comment: I think I got it to work, if the word is occuring multiple times in the array, to find all the locations, do I just change to while(i ==3) ?

Comment: is ++i and ++b used to increment to the next character to check if they match?

Comment: Yes, `++i` for array2 that was input by user and `++b` for array1 pre assigned in program...

Comment: why do you have to count it before instead of after? like i++ and b++ ?

Comment: Its the same here its just why to increment for granted when you can do it at place...